# _veriff_js_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I get the following error thrown in the browser. What should I do to prevent this error from popping ?

> *veriff_js_sdk__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_ is not a function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as Veriff from '@veriff/js-sdk';

@Component({
  selector: 'hp',
  templateUrl: './hp-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hp-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  hpclicked(){

    const veriff = Veriff({
      apiKey: 'API_KEY',
      parentId: 'veriff-root',
      onSession: function(err : Error, response : Response) {
        console.log("executed");
      }
    });
    veriff.setParams({
      person: {
        givenName: 'Foo',
        lastName: 'Bar'
      },
      vendorData: '7eb19312-79d6-11ec-90d6-0242ac120003'
    });
    veriff.mount({
      submitBtnText: 'Get verified'
    });
   
   }
}
```

Note:

### Package                         Version

@angular/cli                    11.2.19

typescript                      4.1.6